# HTML input button css-height not working on Safari and Chrome

Tags: html, button, input, height, submit

I have a very basic question. I am setting height to 50px for my html form submit button. It works on Firefox but not Chrome nor Safari. The code is as simple as following:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" style="height:50px;" />
```

Any idea how to make it work on Chrome and Safari?

Comment: I'm not sure why this doesn't work alone, but I know if you add a background color it will read your `height` attribute: `<input type="submit" value="Send" style="background: #eee; height: 50px;"/>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`

Comment: It works in Safari 5 and Chrome 20 when no other CSS is involved. Please consider editing your question to include your CSS.

Comment: well it's working for me perhaps you have more css that you are not showing us?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Change it from `<input>` to `<button>` and add `-webkit-appearance: none;` to the start of your CSS, eg:

```
.submitbtn {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    color:#666;
    font-weight:bold;
    border: solid #666 1px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Actually...I stand corrected. My problem was fixed by increasing the font size, changing it to a `button` did not solve it for me. Like the OP it worked fine in Firefox but didn't change in Safari, which was important for me as I wanted it to work on the iPhone.

Comment: Just adding -webkit-appearance: none; on my <input> worked perfect for me.

Comment: I came here while solving a problem that the <input> button was rendering as text. Adding -webkit-appearance: none; solved my problem too.

Answer (score 15):

Just adding `-webkit-appearance: none;` on my `<input>` worked for me on safari browser on Macbook.

Answer (score 6):

This should be working also.

```
  -webkit-appearance:default-button;
```

There are quite a few parameters for this property that you may want to take advantage of and/or watch out for. Also, If you simply wanted to disable inner-shadows of input fields you could just use -webkit-appearance:caret;.

```
button
button-bevel
caret
checkbox
default-button
listbox
listitem
media-fullscreen-button
media-mute-button
media-play-button
media-seek-back-button
media-seek-forward-button
media-slider
media-sliderthumb
menulist
menulist-button
menulist-text
menulist-textfield
none
push-button
radio
searchfield
searchfield-cancel-button
searchfield-decoration
searchfield-results-button
searchfield-results-decoration
slider-horizontal
slider-vertical
sliderthumb-horizontal
sliderthumb-vertical
square-button
textarea
textfield
```

Comment: Are all those values relevant to this particular question?  Can you perhaps narrow it down to a couple of the most relevant ones?

Comment: That are the possible vars for what I said -webkit-appearance:button; as example.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Şήøωў](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4595310/%C5%9E%CE%AE%C3%B8%CF%89%D1%9E)'s <sup>(upvoted)</sup>[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450776/html-input-button-css-height-not-working-on-safari-and-chrome/28666000#28666000):

@ Safari 11.0.2 (13604.4.7.1.3) @ macOS 10.13.2 (17C88)
e.g.

```
input[type=button]{
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}
```

solved my issue (of only `-size` of mostly [`-webkit-`]`font-`* having very limited effect);
overriding "User Agent Stylesheet":

```
input:matches([type="button"], [type="submit"], [type="reset"]){
  -webkit-appearance: push-button;
}
```