# Basic CSS button styling not working

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SHOUT" />
```

Here is the CSS:

```
input[type="submit"] {
    height: 50px;
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't amend the size of the submit button. Could there be any reason for this?

Comment: Could you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Here is a [JSFiddle to demonstrating that your code resizes the input](http://jsfiddle.net/e8se0zer/):  . Is your posted code different in some way than the code you are testing?

Comment: Check whether any other style properties are overriding using Developer tools(F 12)

Comment: @GeorgeCummins that isn't working in Chrome for Mac.

Comment: What browser(s) are you seeing this issue in?

Comment: I can confirm that this code does not work in Chrome; it probably has to do with the type of display of input elements (inline / block /inline-block)

Comment: @jsve Interesting. It works for me in Firefox and Chrome (latest) on Ubuntu. Is Mac OS the common factor between you and bcole, I wonder?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450776/html-input-button-css-height-not-working-on-safari-and-chrome

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/vLo3s2d5/

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Doesn't work in Safari for Mac either. It does work in FF for Mac, Chrome for Windows, FF for Windows, and IE 11.

Comment: @Pearson confirmed: that works on Chrome for Mac and Safari for Mac.

Comment: @bcole while it may be a similar question to the one you link to, the solution presented on your linked question I really doubt would be applicable in this case (I may be wrong but....)

Comment: what if use `button` element over `input` tag. For example  how about using this way `<button type="submit">Submit Text</button>`

Comment: Apologies as I have never used JSFiddle:    http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=EBiRT4cIIL

Comment: @jimbo123 try to put `-webkit-appearance: button;` in your CSS file.

Answer (score -2):

The same code you provided seems to work fine. Did you add reference to css file properly?

```css
input[type="submit"] {
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SHOUT" />
```

Comment: This was not mentioned in your question :) Please update your question.

Comment: ahh I didn't think that would be an issue let me double check

Comment: @Vim use an "@" sign to notify of having commented.

Answer (score -2):

Some possible solutions:

- set the value to **important** : `height:50px !important;`
- check that nothing else overwrites the value in CSS. Typically use Firebug or similar to check this in your browser window (see [here](https://getfirebug.com/)).
- Set a `min-height` value and/or a `max-height` value to the same as the standard height.

I can't give you more specific advice without a link or a fiddle to play with.