# CSS issue under Google Chrome (Textbox and Button)

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with the positioning of a textbox and button, where it doesn't display correctly under Chrome.

Here is an example from each browser, as you can see the textbox under Chrome is pushed out of position.

Internet Explorer/Firefox

[image: Internet Explorer]

Chrome

[image: Chrome1]

html:

```
<div id="divSearch">
   <input type="text" id="txtSearch" placeholder=" Search..."/>
   <input type="submit" id="btnSearch" value=""/>
</div>`
```

css:

```
input[type=text]{
    width: 200px;
    height: 24px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    padding: 0;
}

input[type="submit"]{
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url(../img/search_button.png) no-repeat;
    background-color: white;
    background-position: 10px 5px;
}

#divSearch{
float: right;
width: 300px;
height: 40px;
white-space: nowrap;
margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Now if I remove the height from `input[type="submit"]` the positioning is fine except the button is now the wrong size.

[image: Chrome2]

I can't work out why the height of the button causes the issue. Any advice on how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML input button css-height not working on Safari and Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450776/html-input-button-css-height-not-working-on-safari-and-chrome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following code. It should work:

```
input[type=text]{
  float:left
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, such an easy fix thank you. Do you know why the float left helped?

Comment: As floating rule says, if you are floating an element then each and every Element should be floated. you used flow for only for #divSearch and not to input elements. Anyways this was the one trick to solve the problem using float.

Answer (score 0):

Make the button value non-empty will resolve this.

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSearch" value="&nbsp;"/>
```

The root cause is the button has no text baseline.