# a tags not showing any content and are not clickable

Tags: safari, anchor

All the tags are working perfectly in all other browsers except for safari. They are not even clickable. I used one of the previous suggestions and wrote my ids in the form of index.html/#id but then the tags stopped displaying alltogether. Here's my menu code please help me out. The tag content is not even visible. like the menu is not even showing the home option in my page but when i remove a tag the home option gets displayed.

```
<li style="margin-top:80px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding- 
right:55px;"><a href="index.php" class="navlink active">Home</a></li>       
<li style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-right:55px;"><a     
href="#about" class="navlink smoothscroll">About Us</a></li>
```

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450776/html-input-button-css-height-not-working-on-safari-and-chrome - Try updating your style attribute with "-webkit-appearance: none".

Comment: It is still not working. Wierd part is it is not even showing the menu options,  let alone being able to be clickable. But only on safari

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you used `<html>` and `<body>` tags in your code but I added them and everything works. I tried it on Safari 5.1.7 for Windows.
Here is the code:

```
<html>
   <body>
    <li style="margin-top:80px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding- right:55px;">
        <a href="index.php" class="navlink active">Home</a>
    </li>       
    <li style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-right:55px;">
        <a href="#about" class="navlink smoothscroll">About Us</a>
    </li>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have added html and body tags in the code. I did not send the entire page code here. It's still not working . Can '<!DOCTYPE html > create problem?